# did ISIS adhere to rules of slavery with the Yazidis of the Sinjar regions

Tags: slavery, jihad

I've been trying to understand Islamic Slavery and it's history. I heard about what happened to the Yazidis and tried reading the reports by the UN and It sounded terrible. was it in the law of Islamic law?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say whether they adhere to Islamic Law because nothing could be understood from Western media sources. They lie a lot

Regarding the matter with Yazidis if they were captured them in the first place.
They practiced what was the norm in the medieval era irrespective of religion (Slavery through war].

Comment: Yazidis are polytheists. So they shouldn't have been concubines in the first place [Is it permissible to marry a Yazidi woman?]https://islamqa.info/en/answers/203158/is-it-permissible-to-marry-a-yazidi-woman

Comment: There is a difference of opinion over this matter.
Some said it is permissible citing the case of a Ghazwa during the lifetime of Prophet.